Applying Li-Yau-Hamilton estimate to heat kernel
In Li-Yau gradient estimate one apply maximum principle to the quantity $F(x,t)=t(|\nabla u|^2-\alpha u_t)$ where $u$ is a positive solution of heat equation on $M$. It seems that maximum principle can be applied since $F\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow 0$.
Similarly in matrix harnack estimate of Hamilton one apply Hamilton's matrix maximum principle to $u_{ij}-\frac{u_iu_j}{u}+\frac{f}{2t}g_{ij}$ and again it is assumed that this matrix quantity goes to $+\infty$ because of $\frac{f}{2t}g_{ij}$ term.
In both cases it seems that to have a desired initial condition one needs to assume $u$ is smoothly continued as $t\rightarrow 0$, i.e. has a smooth initial data $u_0$.
However I saw in the literature these estimates are applied to the heat kernel, which does not has a smooth initial data. I guess it has something to do with asymptotics of heat kernel as $t\rightarrow 0$, but I cannot find the explicit justification for that. So my question is, how one can apply Li-Yau and Hamilton estimates for solution of heat equation with possibly singular initial data, such as heat kernel?
